# How can I shorten css-code from repeating ID (css)

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I shorten my css code? 
**HTML:**

```
<div id="root">
    <p>Green</p>
    <h1>Blue</h1>
    <h3 class="brown">Brown</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#root p{ color:green; }

#root h1{ color:blue; }

#root .brown{ color:brown; }
```

I know above codes are working fine.
But I may just thinking **if there is any way of shortening css code above**. I tried these(below) but didn't work.

```
#root{
  p{ color:green; },
  h1{ color:blue; },
  .brown{ color:brown; }
}
```

Can somebody give me a demo(codepen) on how to do it. Need your help sirs..

Comment: what you have tried is a SASS/LESS syntax

Comment: In css, you cant do that. You should either use sass or less which are css preprocessors.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  could you do SASS/LESS way for me Sir please. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @BearNithi sorry for my ignorance (just starting learning css). Could you do SASS/LESS way Sir for me please.

Comment: you need to read about and understand it ... it's not as simple as *doing*. You start learning, so keep learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do in SASS almost exactly as you tried to shorten it in CSS just without comma

```
#root{
  p{ color:green; }
  h1{ color:blue; }
  .brown{ color:brown; }
}
```

Here you have link to official guide > https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the css in [**SCSS**](https://sass-lang.com/guide) as follows with the parent selector outside, In our case it's `#root`, Inside it curly braces, we can declare the child selectors of the `#root`.

Use [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) for compiling sass file to css

**SCSS**

```
#root{
  p{ color:green; }
  h1{ color:blue; }
  .brown{ color:brown; }
}
```

**COMPILED CSS**

```
#root p {
  color: green;
}
#root h1 {
  color: blue;
}
#root .brown {
  color: brown;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with SASS, for example.

```
#root {
  p {color: green;}
  & h1 {color: blue;} 
  & h3 {color: brown;}
}
```

You can test it here, to see it working: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Go here to know how to install it in your project: https://sass-lang.com/install

This is what it will look like in css, but using SASS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in other comments, [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) is perfectly suited for writing nested CSS declarations. Do note that it is a *preprocessor*, so the final CSS code will be compiled. My guess is that the result of this sass code:

```
#root{
  p{ color:green; }
  h1{ color:blue; }
  .brown{ color:brown; }
}
```

will result in your example as output.

Just saying this because it is important to know that the final file will not necessarily be smaller.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is same descriptive as Your questions.
Here You go:

```
p{color:#0f0}h1{color:#00f}.brown{color:brown}
```

;)